What is the keyboard short cut for inserting a Python Chunk in VsCode?
I can't find any real information or answers to this in stack or in my google searches. If there's something I'm missing, please let me know.
I am taking a data science class in which we do all of our work in vs code in a qmd file. When working in r studio for other classes, I have used ctrl+alt+i to add an r chunk. Is there a keyboard shortcut to add a python chunk into a qmd file in vs code?
I really can't find anything. I've asked chat gpt, google, and looked here on stack overflow.

I'm sure you can set up a custom keyboard shurtcut that inserts the required couple of characters?
